# Room Thread, RxJava, select issue

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-room

I have a weird issue with Room and Rx completable. Easy to reproduce though. The issue is from the thread, but don't understand why..

When I subscribe to Rx completable and wait for the success of an insert, the next selection (select max, or count) on the result table is not working when using another thread.

```
val entryTable = TestDbUtil.createEntryTable(
               entry.id, // 1
               entryTableFieldId, // 1
               rowIndexExpected // row index: 123
            )

            // Insert a row in entry table object with entry.id = 1 and field.id = 1 and row index is 1234
            // The insert is a Completable, we subscribe to it to get the result insertion
            // When insert is success, we are looking to get the max row index from it.
            entryTableDao.insert(entryTable).subscribe({

                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute { // With thread I have an error here!!  Without this line it's working fine

                    val max = entryTableDao.findMaxRowIndex(entry.id, entryTable.fieldId)
                    Assert.assertEquals(rowIndexExpected, max) // Always 0 but should be 123
                }
            }, 
            { error ->
                Assert.assertNull(error)
            }

...
```

I tried multiple things, like rx everywhere, but I have the same issue..
It's maybe an issue related to the transaction?

**Edit**

With the comments, it's ok for me to do like said, doOnComplete and use of Schedulers.from(executor).. That's working for my TU, but in my application nothing is working..

Here the code:

```
fun getMaxIndex(entryId: String, fieldId: Int): LiveData<Int> {
    val result = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    entryTableDao.findMaxRowIndex(entryId, fieldId)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSuccess {
            // Never called even if there are some data in db...
            result.value = it
        }
        .doOnError {
            // Not called.
            result.value = 0
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            // Always called, obviously, but I don't have the onSuccess.
            result.value = 0
        }
        .subscribe()
    return result
}
```

Questions:

1. How can I test this behaviour in my TU? Like observeOn main thread, because I can't reproduce it.
2. In the second code snippet, what is the difference between, subscribe {result ->} and doOnSuccess { result -> }
3. In the second code snippet, why do I haven't any response data? I spent so much time on this issue... I can't figure it out...

The TU call the findMaxRowIndex after result success from insert, in my app it's the same behaviour, even if the code doesn't show it.

Comment: For starters you could try to combine it with an operator, like andThen or doOnComplete. This should be a good starting point.

Comment: Exactly, just read the documentation and so that.

Comment: I will try to debug this snippet later today.

Comment: No need, whit doOnComplete it's working fine. I didn't know that I had to use only doOnComplete. I misunderstood rx with observable..

Comment: Hum.... I have to read the documentation again, because Completable with only doOnComplete is not working in my app.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating an Executor in subscribe, that's what observeOn + Schedulers.from(executor) are for.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments a combination with doOnComplete will suffice for what you need. Completable has onComplete and onError so if you need to do something after that you could use doOnComplete. 
Below is the official documentation of Completable: [Completable: doOnComplete](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#doOnComplete-io.reactivex.functions.Action-)
In case you need to make things on a background thread you should use the RxJava subscribeOn. More here: [Understanding RxJava subscribeOn and observeOn](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea) . In case you want to use an Executor you can still do it via

> Schedulers.from(Executor executor)

Comment: It's not a solution in my case. I have edited my question, because, it's working for my TU. But not in the app, I don't know why....